# namespace troubles with enums

Tags: c++

Having a problem using enumerations with namespaces.

Below is the function call:

```
object->writeMessage(tmpZone->getLineOne(), tmpZone->getLine(), tmpZone->getPosition());
```

the problem from the compiler comes from

```
tmpZone->getLine()
```

the prototype for getLine() from the Zone class(which is in the insight namespace)is:

```
Line getLine();
```

which returns an enum type in the insight namespace. This function call is in a cpp file under a using namespace insight; line.

the compiler errors are

> C:/WindRiver/workspace/SimpleTemplate/InsightLT.cpp: In static member
>   function `static int
>   insight::InsightLT::taskFunction(insight::InsightLT*)':
>   C:/WindRiver/workspace/SimpleTemplate/InsightLT.cpp:161: error: no
>   matching function for call to`
>   insight::InsightLT::writeMessage(std::string, Line, int)'
>   C:/WindRiver/workspace/SimpleTemplate/InsightLT.cpp:82: note:
>   candidates are: void insight::InsightLT::writeMessage(std::string,
>   insight::Line, int)

I can't think of why this is happening. The Zone class is defined with in the insight namespace as well. Any ideas guys?

Comment: What is the prototype of the `getLine()` function?

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example that illustrates the error.

Comment: does `getPosition()` return an `int`, or something which is convertible to an `int`? and does `getLineOne()` return a `string`, or something which is convertible to a `string`? why do you say the problem comes from `getLine()`? I can't deduce that from the compiler error

Comment: sorry, getLine one returns a string and getPosition returns and int. The mismatch is in the compiler output stating that is expects insight::Line and is getting Line.

Comment: I don't think the error isn't because `insight::Line` isn't resolvable. Clearly it is or the compiler would not be complaining that your second parameter isn't one. From here it appears the `Line` *type* provided to the template-expansion of `InsightLT::writeMessage` for your call is *not* `insight::Line`. It is `Line` from somewhere else. However, without seeing more code I can't tell where the `Line` object `getLine()` is coming from, nore its type. Unless you provide more, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler can't resolve `Line` from `insight namespace`, you could provide full namespace in function definition, also wrap cpp inside `namespace insight`.

Try:

```
namespace insight {
  void InsightLT::writeMessage(std::string, insight::Line, int)
  {    
  }
}
```

Comment: I have wrapped the function definition inside the insight namespace as you have described

Comment: try provide full namesapce for Line as well

Comment: no luck. I specified the full namespace in the prototype as well as the definition of writeMessage.

Comment: did you update writeMessage in InsightLT.h  as well?

Comment: Yes, I updated the declaration of writeMessage which is in another class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to compile, though I don't know why what I did worked. For the sake of completeness and closure I wanted to put it here.

I was declaring the Line enum and another enum inside the namespace scope along with another class. I removed the enums and put them in their own header files within the same namespace as before and it now compiles.

I am not sure what I was missing that this fixed the issue. If someone has any considerations please comment as to what this might have fixed.

Thanks for those that tried to help and sorry I wasn't able to put together an example the displayed the error.